# How do I find the mapping between profile fields and merge fields

Tags: 7, emails

I am using the Mailchimp module, version 7.x-3.6.

The client has asked for an extra merge field for *Gender*. At the moment, we just have *First Name*, *Last Name*, Username, and UID.

> [image: screenshot]

When I visit /admin/config/services/mailchimp/fields, 
I see a *field_profile_mailchimp* field on my profile2 main bundle. This is just a checkbox field with a value indicating the user must be included on the mailchimp list or not.

Where is the mapping between the fields on the profile2 main bundle (*field_profile_name* is *First Name*, *field_profile_last_name* is *Last Name*) and the merge fields in Mailchimp?

Comment: I am late to respond this answer, but it can help others finding the answers. Here is perfect explanation of merge fields and Drupal mapping with MailChimp fields: https://drupalize.me/videos/collect-additional-information-merge-fields